# What is the correct grammar?

Tags: grammar

Which phrase is correct grammar?
At a recent funeral of a married couple whu died 2 days apart, the funeral home printed the following phrase on the bulletin.

"2 life's well lived"
Or
"2 lives well lived"

Which phrase is the correct grammar?

Thank you

Comment: Both of those are incorrect; the first one is egregious, the second one somewhat incorrect. Both are in very poor taste.

Comment: *Two lives well lived* is the correct one. Not 2 but Two. Since we don't use numbers in English but their spellings

Comment: Thank you. I don't remember if 2 or two was used, the question was really about the word LIFE'S.

Answer (score 2):

> *Two lives well lived*

The first is grammatically incorrect for a few reasons:

1. The plural form of "life" is "lives"
2. The apostrophe is an incorrect and unnecessary use of the possessive.
3. Generally numbers less than 100, especially when written formally, are spelled out.

Comment: In regard to your third point: this is *especially* so in reference to the dead.  If I were to read a eulogy that said *'2 lives well lived',* it would come across as an insult through lack of care.

Comment: @Anonym couldn't agree with you more.